# Shell command to split large file into 10 smaller files

Tags: shell, cygwin

I have a csv import file with 33 million lines that need to be imported into my database. I can import it with a C# console app but then the stored procedures that run after the import timeout. Consequently I want to split the file into 10 smaller files.

I could do it in C# but I suspect there's a much better approach using shell utilities. I have cygwin installed and can use all the common Linux shell utilities. Is there a neat little combination of commands I could use to split the file?

Comment: What database? With the major ones there are import utilities you can use to make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `split` - e.g. to split a file every 3.4 million lines (should give you 10 files):

`split -l 3400000`

[$ man split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split)

Answer (score 10):

splitting by line is good however you can also split by size

creates 1MB files out of the original

```
split -b 1024k <file_name>
```

creates 1GB files out of original

```
split -b 1024m <file_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of split in coreutils 8.8 (not yet released) will have the command

```
split -n l/10
```

For now you'll need to specify a particular number of lines per file

Answer (score 1):

If your csv file have 500 rows to split two part(250+250)

download and install "Cygwin Terminal"

put comment "split -l 250 filename.csv"