# Python Splitting a Text File

Tags: python, file, text

I will do some process on a text file which is currently taking large amount of time. I observed from activity monitor that currently the application uses only 1 threads so I decided to split file into multiprocessing.cpu_count() equal files and do the same process in them seperately.

My code as follows:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    "do the process"
```

I want to change this into:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    files = f.splitinto(cpu_count)
    for file in files:
        "start the threads to do the same process for each file"
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You look as though you've got it under control.

Comment: There is no method like f.splitinto to split a file into multiple files. That is the thing im looking for.

Comment: Ah. Okay. What do you mean by split a file into multiple files? Splitting how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22751000/7486918 may be able to help you.

Comment: This is a bash command. I want these processes to be handled in my application without creating new files.

Answer (score 1):

`file.readlines()` gives you the lines of the text file as a list. That means if you have a text file with 100 lines, `readlines()` will give you a `list` of length 100 - where each item is a line from your file. Following on from this, you can do:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    lines_list[0] = lines[0:len(lines)/cpu_count)
    # ... and so on..
```

After which you can divide the lines and process them however you want to.

Comment: Consider a file of 5 GB. Won't this consume too much memory?

Comment: It will. Then you'd write want a separate function to split the original file into several files and then process those files using the code you already have.

My point is, if you have a text file, the easiest way to divide it up is by lines.