# Split big file in multiple files in python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, file, split

I want to split the file into multiple files if file size of file_write is greater than 20MB.
In Random function, I am opening big_file.txt and removing noise using remove_noise() and writing clean line to outfile.
I am not sure how to split the file based on the size in my current implementation. Please find the code below:
(Apologies for not providing proper implementation with example because it is really complicated)
I have gone through the example at this link: [Split large text file(around 50GB) into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751000/split-large-text-filearound-50gb-into-multiple-files)

```
import os
def parses(lines, my_date_list):
    for line in reversed(list(lines)):
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        date_string = "2019-11-01" # assumption
        yield date_string, line


def remove_noise(line):
    """ dummy function"""
    return line



def random_function(path, output, cutoff="2019-10-31"):

    my_date_list = []
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path) as f:
            lines = parses(f, my_date_list)
            for date, line in lines:
                if cutoff <= date:
                    results = remove_noise(line)
                    output.write(results + '\n')
                    continue
                else:
                    break
```

While writing lines to `output`, I need to check size. If size reached 20MB and I want to write it to second {may be `output_2`} and so on.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "./big_file.txt"
    file_write = "./write_file.txt"
    with open(file_write) as outfile:
        random_function(path=path, output=outfile)
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/filesplit/ might be useful to you: FileSplit(file='path/to/file', splitsize=20 * 2**20, output_dir='/path/to/output directory/')