# split the CSV file python

Tags: python

I am creating output file using the python code and due its size , the user is not able to open it.
I need to split the file into two files , how can I do it using python.
is there any in built function I can use to split the file .

below is code i am trying :

```
with pd.read_csv(File_Path, chunksize=60000) as reader:
        for i,chunk in enumerate(reader):
        chunk.to_csv(f'File_Path{i}.csv', index=False)
```

getting below error:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: can you specify what kind class object you are trying to store and if possible provide a sample.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split large text file(around 50GB) into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751000/split-large-text-filearound-50gb-into-multiple-files)

Comment: That error has nothing to do with what you're asking. Ignoring the indentation, the code looks fine at a glance, so I've closed this question as a duplicate regarding the indentation error only. In the future, please start your troubleshooting by doing your own research, like googling the error message. See [ask] for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to help you segregate the chunk based on set amount lines. And once you reach that many lines in the document you move to creating a new file. If I have a sample here might be even be able to help you write its function.

Answer (score -1):

One way might be to use python's logging functions and make csv files on a daily basis (Timed rotating file handler).

Comment: We dont know if it is a daily based report